# Add custom colors to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My main goal is to color elements differently in my plot. To do so, I `manually` added an extra column with the desired color for each `category`:

```
mtcars$color[mtcars$carb = 4] = '#F98866'
mtcars$color[mtcars$carb = 3] = '#68829E'
mtcars$color[mtcars$carb = 2] = '#FF420E'
mtcars$color[mtcars$carb = 1] = '#89DA59'

p <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
    geom_point(aes(wt, mpg,
                   size = disp,
                   color = mtcars$color))# + scale_color_manual(values = mtcars$color)
```

But when I run the above code, I get this as an output:
[image]
Instead of my `specified` colors, I get the preset `ggplot` colors.

But if I uncomment the last line, I **partially** get what I'm looking for--only one of the colors I wanted.

[image]

How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: `+ scale_color_identity()`? (And just use `color = color`, no `$` within `aes`.)

Comment: @Henrink what If I don't want to color based on a range? what then? let's say I want to color based on values? `1=red`, `2=blue`, etc...

Comment: @Axeman can you write an answer. I'm not sure I follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
    geom_point(aes(wt, mpg, size = disp, color = color)) + 
    scale_color_identity(guide = 'legend')
```

[image]